# How to know when the cursor has halted somewhere?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

I have a graph, and I want to display the value onder the cursor by using the default tooltip (set by the `Title` attribute). To show the right value in the tooltip, I could calculate the value each time the mouse moves over the graph, so that if the mouse pauses it shows the right tooltip. But this calculation requires a lot of performance, so I'd rather wait with updating the text in the `Title` attribute, until the cursor is halted, so that I don't do unnecessary calculations for a tooltip that is invisible.

Is there an event for this?

Comment: Something like [this `mousestop` plugin](http://richardscarrott.co.uk/posts/view/jquery-mousestop-event)?

Comment: @lonesomeday Thanks.. If you add that as anwer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to build a custom event that is fired after the mouse has become stationary within an element. Something like a `mousestop` event.

Fortunately, [this plugin](http://richardscarrott.co.uk/posts/view/jquery-mousestop-event) seems to provide this functionality for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, i think it will helps you

```
<title id="title_id">example</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function set_title(val) {
     $("#title_id").html(val);
 }
</script>
<input type="text" name="time" value="" onchange="set_title(this.value);">
```

when you change the value in the input field, the title will change

Comment: I dont mean the document title like in your example, I mean the title attribute of a div (when you hover it is displayed). And more importantly: your example still needs to set the title value on 'onchange', while in my case the frequency of this is too high (every mousemove instead of every keypress).